# Finding no elements in page

Tags: python, selenium

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/navigation/nba')
time.sleep(20)
root = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="root"]')
games = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="ae aj iq s h i j ak l m al o am q an"]')
```

I asked this question a few days ago, the code was able to be fixed to find the root item. I am able to find the root item, but the individual games are contained in the div above. I am unable to find that or any other items on the page.

The page gives a message about in the top of the inspect screen
You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

Could this been an issue?

I've scrapped a number of these, I haven't had an issue before this site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first you could use `print( driver.page_source )` to see what you really get from server

Comment: I checked page in Chrome and Firefox and it doesn't have `div` with class `"ae aj iq s h i j ak l m al o am q an"` - you use wrong value. For example: `ae` in only one item - with class `"t ab ac w ad x ae af h as ah"`

Comment: It seems like they are switching the class name

Comment: (//div[@style="flex-direction: column; overflow: hidden auto; display: flex; min-width: 0px;"])[1]/div[position()>2 and position() <13] would work but it's pretty ugly.

Comment: Arundeep, I noticed that, crazy. Why would they do that? is there an easy way to get around it

Comment: Depends on how they structure their elements. Switching classes like this tend to go with xpath judging by how they are using their classes as elements for style as well. It's mostly to stop botting from occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy stuff

fix was:

```
   date = event.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@style="cursor: pointer;"]/div[1]/span').text

   Awayteam = event.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@style="cursor: pointer;"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/span').text

   Hometeam = event.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@style="cursor: pointer;"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/span').text
```

Basically, the link the game page (a href) was a stable element. Find it by style, then use xpath under it to get the item without having to look by class. Will monitoring going forward, but for now, seems to work. Thanks all for the assistance.